# Decay filter function for a no-limit value with ElasticSearch

Tags: boost, elasticsearch

I have the following documents (at least 1 000 000) in an ElasticSearch index:

```
{"title":"toto", "views":132, "likes":23, "date" : "2014-09-01..." ...}
```

Where title is indexed with a lang analyser, views and likes fields are integer from 0 to infinite, and the date is a ..date field.

I want to search by title, and boost documents if they are recent and have a high views and likes.

I am using a decay filter function for the date (from today as origin), it's working as expected, but I don't know how to do for boosting the views and likes fields, since I have no max-origin.

Here my search query:

```
POST /threads/_search
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "air france",
               "type": "phrase",
               "fields": [
                  "title^4",
                  "desc"
               ]
            }
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "exp": {
                  "date": {
                     "origin": "2014/09/29 13:00:00",
                     "scale": "12h",
                     "offset":"6h",
                     "decay":0.5
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the query you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a "field_value_factor", as per [this section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html#_literal_factor_literal) in the documentation. And you'd need to test and assess the results, modify the "factor" and the boost you are giving to "title" and then test again and see if it's getting closer to what you need. Also, you can use `search=explain` to see how ES computes the _score. Something like this:

```
POST /threads/_search?explain
{
  "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "air france",
               "type": "phrase",
               "fields": [
                  "title^8",
                  "desc"
               ]
            }
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "exp": {
                  "date": {
                     "origin": "2014/09/29 13:00:00",
                     "scale": "12h",
                     "offset":"6h",
                     "decay":0.5
                  }
               }
            },
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "views",
                "modifier": "log2p",
                "factor": 0.1
              }
            },
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "likes",
                "modifier": "log2p",
                "factor": 0.1
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, didn't read this part of the doc! I will give it a try asap.